# How to bill multiple Sale Orders into single Invoice in NetSuite SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to create a invoice against multiple sales orders along with GL impact.
When I using below api that time multiple invoices are creating but i want only single invoice and with GL/accounting impact-
var invoiceRecord = record.transform({fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,fromId: salesOrderId,toType: record.Type.INVOICE, isDynamic: true });

How would I do that?
Any help/suggestions would be highly appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with standard functionality.

Netsuite have a SuiteSolution for Consolidated Invoicing.. You should speak with your NetSuite/Partner Account Manager

Comment: Consolidated Invoicing is not the solution for my client.. They want invoice to be created only one for all the Orders at a time..

Comment: It's not possible